# ember-i18n precompiled translations with Handlebars Runtime

Tags: ember.js, ember-i18n

[ember-i18n readme file](https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n#requirements) says:

> if you haven't precompiled your translations, you'll need to include
>   the full Handlebars, not just handlebars-runtime.js in your
>   application.

Problem is that even using precompiled templates, once we use function **Em.I18n.t** like the following, it still calls Handlebars compilation function, requiring full Handlebars.

Anyone knows a solution for that? Maybe there is a best practice for precompiling translations even for function calls?

Comment: Best solution is not to use ember-i18n. This is just one of the problems with this poorly designed component.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I have urgency for this case, that's the way I've fixed it:

```
/* Customized version of translation compiler */
Em.I18n.compile = function(template) {
    // Full Handlebars completely disabled
    //if (typeof window.Handlebars.compile === 'function')
    //    return window.Handlebars.compile(template);

    return function(context, options){
        var ret = template;
        if (context !== undefined) {
            $.each(context, function(key, value){
                ret = ret.replace("{{"+key+"}}", value);
            });
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

That works pretty well enough, but I not 100% confident it covers all possible situations.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of ember-i18n (2.2.1 as of writing this) has this console message when running it:

***Ember.I18n will no longer include Handlebars compilation by default in the future; instead, it will supply its own default compiler. Set Ember.ENV.I18N_COMPILE_WITHOUT_HANDLEBARS to true to opt-in now.***

So looks like you can, as of now, opt out of using Handlebars compilation and this will be the default going forward in future releases.  This is probably too late for your needs, but maybe others with the same problem will find it useful.